# vscode Beautify Extension doesn't work in html

Tags: html, visual-studio-code

why the  Beautify extension doesn't work on html files? 
maybe there is some way to set this extension to work on html files?

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways to format code using beautify.

1. Using command palette (Manually)

Open command palette using Ctrl+Shift+P or Command+P on macOS and
search

> format document with

Enter and select document formatter.

2. Change default settings (Automatically)
   Go to the settings.
   Search :

   editor.defaultFormatter

Change the  default formatter, then the code will be automatically formatted whenever you save the file.